# How to push String in String in Rust?

Tags: rust, string-concatenation

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut str = "string".to_string();

    // How do I push String to String?
    str.push_str(format!("{}", "new_string"));
}
```

So, how do I push the formatted string in `str`? I don't want to concatenate. Concatenation is kinda' the same thing as push but I want to know how I can push `String` instead.

Comment: `str.push_str(&format!("{}", "new_string"));`

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Thanks, that works. But how is `&String` allowed?

Comment: I'll write a proper answer :)

Comment: @SvetlinZarev That would be great. Thanks.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, `push_str()` accepts a `&str` rather than `String` because it has to copy the data anyway, so it doesn't gain anything by consuming the `String` it receives. And if you have an owned string, it's trivial to obtain a reference, as shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot push `String` directly, but you can push a string slice - i.e. - `&str`. Therefore you have to get a slice from your `String`, which can be done in several ways:

- By calling the [`string.as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str) method
- By taking advantage by the automatic [deref coercion](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html). Because `String` implements [`Deref<Target=str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref), the compiler will automatically convert the string reference (i.e. `&String`) to a string slice - `&str`.

Thus, it's enough to get reference to the formatted string  in order to push it:

```rust
fn main() {
  let mut str = "string".to_string();
  str.push_str(&format!("{}", "new_string"));
}
```

Comment: Note that in this specific case `str.push_str ("new_string")` avoids a superfluous allocation and copy. And in case of more complicated format strings, `write!(&mut str, "{}", 42)` also avoids extra allocations and copies.